# How to reverse xpath for subreport in jasper?

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports, xmldatasource

I try to navigate through xml nodes in the reverse direction when I create a subreport but this is not working. My report XPath is `/root/parent/child1` and I want a subreport to have `/root/parent/child2` as XPath

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <child1>
    </child1>
    <child2>
    </child2>
  </parent>
</root>
```

I wrote the following in the data source expression:

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("//../child2")
```

My question is a general question about xpath:

Is it allowed to refer ancestors in the datasource expression with ".." or "../.."?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying [**`subDataSource`**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRXmlDataSource.html#subDataSource-java.lang.String-)

> Creates a sub data source **using the current node (record) as the root** of the document

Hence your are creating a new document with a new root at child1 (XPath can't go beyond this new root)

Instead use [**`dataSource`**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRXmlDataSource.html#dataSource-java.lang.String-)

> Creates a sub data source **using as root document the document used by "this" data source**.

In your example that would be:

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/root/parent/child2")
```